# Replace part of a string depending on the string content

Tags: php, html, regex, string

Example of markup:

```
<p> a paragraph </p>
<pre lang="html">
  &lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
</pre>
<code lang="html">
  &lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
</code>
```

How can I select all the stuff between `<pre>`,`</pre>`,`<code>`,`</code>` and run a function on it? Trough this function I need to pass 3 arguments: the part of the string that's selected (`&lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;`), the container type (`pre` or `code`), and the parameters of the container (like `lang="html"`).

The function should change the selected part of the string based on the other 2 parameters (if it's relevant I want run the [GeShi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) highlighter on it), then replace the contents of the original string with it, including the container. Something like:

```
<p> a paragraph </p>
<div class="html pre">
  &lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
</div>
<div class="html code">
  &lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Is this a full HTML page with a root element or only a partial as shown above?

Comment: no, it's partial html block, it's basically a article or a comment containing code samples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should go like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//pre | //code');
```

In some cases (e.g.: if you use getElementsByTagName instead of XPath), you will need to operate on an array to get the proper behaviour (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514979/why-domdocument-getelementsbytagname-give-back-an-half-nodelist)), so you need to copy the nodes to an array. I'll do it for this example:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $array[] = $element;
}

foreach ($array as $element) {
    $tag = $element->tagName;
    $content = $element->textContent;
    $lang = $element->getAttribute('lang');
    $new_content = my_function($tag, $content, $lang);

    $new_element = $dom->createElement('div');
    $new_element->setAttribute('class', "$tag $lang");
    $new_element->nodeValue = $new_content;
    $element->parentNode->replaceChild($new_element, $element);
}
```

Of course, in the example above, the `my_function` is undefined. But it should give you a good idea on the howto.

Note that this won't work on nested elements, like these:

```
<pre lang="html">
  <p>some nested element</p>
  &lt;p&gt; a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
</pre>
```

If you want to work on nested elements, use [a function to get the innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) instead of using `$element->textContent`.

Comment: thank you. I'm sorry to be so stupid, but how do I get the processed string? :) `$new_content` only has the code stuff in it